# Boost unit testing and catching exceptions

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

We have code that throws `std::runtime_error` and we are using the Boost unit testing framework.

At the moment we are using `BOOST_CHECK_THROW`. Unfortunately this does not check that the `what` message.

Is there a version of BOOST_CHECK_THROW that can check that an exception has been raised and that exception has the correct message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look into [BOOST_CHECK_EXCEPTION](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/testing-tools/reference.html), which allows you to specify a predicate on the exception that was thrown. Here's an example I created:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MAIN
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>

void fail()
{
    throw std::logic_error("some error message");
}

void succeed()
{
}

void wrong_msg()
{
    throw std::logic_error("some other error message");
}

bool correctMessage(const std::logic_error& ex)
{
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(ex.what(), std::string("some error message"));
    return true;
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(case_fail)
{
    BOOST_CHECK_EXCEPTION(fail(), std::logic_error, correctMessage);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(case_succeed)
{
    BOOST_CHECK_EXCEPTION(succeed(), std::logic_error, correctMessage);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(case_wrong_msg)
{
    BOOST_CHECK_EXCEPTION(wrong_msg(), std::logic_error, correctMessage);
}
```

Output:

```
Running 3 test cases...
testUnitTest.cpp(31): error in "case_succeed": exception std::logic_error is expected
testUnitTest.cpp(20): error in "case_wrong_msg": check ex.what() == std::string("some error message") failed [some other error message != some error message]

*** 2 failures detected in test suite "Master Test Suite"
```